# Scope issue in function, local variable not defined

Tags: c#

I am getting an error for dateClose.closing, "use is unassigned local variable".  I declared dateClose outside of the for loop and defined the value inside the for loop.  How can I make that value available outside of the for loop?

```
public class SMA
{
    public Models.DateClose SMAMethod (Queue<Models.DateClose> queue, int period)
    {
        decimal average, sum=0;
        Models.DateClose dateClose;
        for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
        {
            dateClose = queue.Dequeue();
            sum += dateClose.Close;
        }
        average = sum/period;
        dateClose.Close = average;  <--- error

        return dateClose;

    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for the error is because the variable hasn't been assigned (i.e. it doesn't have a value assigned to it like 'null' or '1').  The answer by Steve below will fix that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply fix the error by doing

```
Models.DateClose dateClose = null;
```

however you would also want to add a null check to make sure you don't run into null ref exception if queue has no item.

Comment: Steve, this line in the for loop "dateClose = queue.Dequeue();" assigns a value to dateClose.close. Why is it not known outside the for loop?

Comment: @Jam66125 because the line is not guarantee to run (I.E. period = 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. If your `period` variable is greater than the queue count than dateClose.Close will throw an exception.

```
public Models.DateClose SMAMethod (Queue<Models.DateClose> queue, int period)
{
    decimal average, sum=0;
    Models.DateClose dateClose = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
    {
        dateClose = queue.Dequeue();

        if(dateClose != null)
            sum += dateClose.Close;
    }

    average = sum/period;
    dateClose.Close = average;  

    return dateClose;

}
```

**Why do you get this error:**

if you have the class, member variables neednot be initialized:

```
public class Test
{
    private int temp; // this is okay.

..
}
```

However, if you have a local variable, then you need to initialize them:

```
public void Method()
{
int variabl; 

sum += variable; // error.
}
```

So, local variables need to be initialized but member variables neednt be.